# Comparing hierarchical clusterings in R

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I'm using the package `dendextend` and function `cor_cophenetic`to calculate the cophenetic distance between 6 hierarchical clusters. In which R outputs the correlations between them.

Currently the code I'm using is simply:

```
cor_cophenetic(hcr1,hcr2)
cor_cophenetic(hcr1,hcr3)
cor_cophenetic(hcr1,hcr4)
cor_cophenetic(hcr1,hcr5)
cor_cophenetic(hcr1,hcr6)
cor_cophenetic(hcr2,hcr3)
            :
            :
cor_cophenetic(hcr4,hcr6)
cor_cophenetic(hcr5,hcr6)
```

which outputs the correlations individually.

I know there is a function `outer` which can do this but I'm not sure how to incorporate this command into it. I'm trying to get the output as a 15x15 matrix.

Also this is simply calculating the correlations. Is there any method in which I can visually compare two dendrograms?

Comment: If there are only 6 clusters,  why is the matrix 15x15?

Comment: Comparing cluster 1&2, 1&3, 1&4,.....,5&6. 15 all together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After further reading I found out that while `cor_cophenetic()` can't process more than two dendlist elements at a time, `cor.dendlist()` can, and will compute cophenetic correlation (among other things), which makes things a whole lot simpler.

```
names(dend.l) <- met
round(cor.dendlist(dend.l), 4)
#          complete single average centroid
# complete   1.0000 0.4925  0.6044   0.4822
# single     0.4925 1.0000  0.9851   0.9959
# average    0.6044 0.9851  1.0000   0.9871
# centroid   0.4822 0.9959  0.9871   1.0000
```

---

Original answer using `cor_cophenetic()` and example data:

I don't think you can make `outer()` work for this, as it expects an object of type atomic (vector, matrix or array). We'll have to roll our own using `expand.grid()` and `apply()`.

```
library(dendextend)
library(magrittr)

# example data
set.seed(23235)
ss <- sample(1:150, 10 )

dend.l <- dendlist()
met <- c("complete", "single", "average", "centroid")

for (i in 1:length(met)) {
    dend <- iris[ss,-5] %>% dist %>% hclust(met[i])
    dend.l[[i]] <- as.dendrogram(dend)
}

ind <- expand.grid(1:length(dend.l), 1:length(dend.l))

# turns out cor_cophenetic has a method for dendlist where you can
# specify which elements you want to compare. Simplifies things a little
v <- apply(ind, 1, function(x) cor_cophenetic(dend.l, x))
m <- matrix(v, length(dend.l))
dimnames(m) <- list(met, met)

round(m, 4)
#          complete single average centroid
# complete   1.0000 0.4925  0.6044   0.4822
# single     0.4925 1.0000  0.9851   0.9959
# average    0.6044 0.9851  1.0000   0.9871
# centroid   0.4822 0.9959  0.9871   1.0000
```

As you can see the matrix is symmetric, so we could get away with `combn()` instead of `expand.grid`, which would give us just one of the triangles.

As for comparing two dendrograms visually, take a look at [Introduction to dendextend](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dendextend/vignettes/introduction.html) section Comparing two dendrograms.

---

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but this seems to be comparing the different linkage algorithms for one cluster which is testing for similarity between algorithms. If I'm not mistaken then my original question is similar but instead of comparing algorithms I'd like to compare the correlation between clusters.

Comment: @Ali: I just used `cor_cophenetic()` as you did. I have no idea what it does internally.

Comment: It's a measure of similarity between two hierarchical clusters. Your code displays the similarities for one cluster with different linkage algorithms. If you were to just choose one linkage algorithm, lets say `complete` and compare two or more clusters with complete linkage. The code I used will do this instead of comparing the linkage algorithms. i.e. the hierarchical clustering has been applied 6 times, producing 6 different hierarchical clusters. I want to find the correlations between these. Although your code is very helpful in comparing linkages which is something I also had in mind.

Comment: @Ali: Sure, I varied the linkage method because that was something I could do, without having access to your data, to easily produce a few different trees that could serve as an example. If you want to compare your own trees all you have to do is collect them in a `dendlist` object called `dend.l` and run the code.

Comment: Ahh I see, I for some reason believed I wouldn't be able to put a list into the function. Seems to work. Thanks!

Comment: @Ali: Seems you can simplify things a bit by using `cor.dendlist()` instead. Found it on that [link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dendextend/vignettes/introduction.html#correlation-measures) I posted.

Comment: Works very well. Thanks @AkselA!

Comment: Thanks for the answer @AkselA, if you could please update your answer to emphasize that cor.dendlist should solve the issue, that would be helpful for future people who would run into this thread :)

Comment: @TalGalili: I moved that bit to the top.